# Creating matrix in bigquery efficiently

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My input table looks like this with key and value columns

[image: input_table]

Step 1 : I want to construct a table which looks like matrix, with column key as a column and column headers, with values as count of overlapping/intersecting values

[image: matrix_table]

Step 2 : Another matrix like this,

[image: distance_matrix]

To explain a cell [x2,x1], the value is "yes" because it satisfies both the below conditions,

1. (count of x2 values, which is 5) - (value in the previous matrix in the same position [x2,x1], which is 3 in this example) <=3
2. (count of x1 values, which is 5) - (value in the previous matrix in the same position [x2,x1], which is 3 in this example) <=3

To explain a cell [x3,x1], the value is "no" because it does not satisfy both the below conditions,

1. (count of x3 values, which is 7) - (value in the previous matrix in the same position [x3,x1], which is 1 in this example) <=3
2. (count of x1 values, which is 5) - (value in the previous matrix in the same position [x3,x1], which is 1 in this example) <=3

Step 3: Output table should be the ones with "yes"

[image]

What is the most efficient way to do this in google bigquery, I am exploring arrays, any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on the condition where you explain cell [x2,x1] and mention `value in the previous matrix in the same position [x1,x1], which is 3 in this example)`. Also, can you tell me your aim with this ? So I can think broader about it.

Comment: it is [x2,x1] , sorry, edited it

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on the conditions? Also, what is the aim fof creating this table?

Comment: can you try this one, if you are interested in matrix data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483635/fewest-number-of-buckets-to-bag-elements-in-bigquery